# what wrong with java lambda :: expression ? why ? what diff between :: and normal expression?

Tags: java, lambda, nullpointerexception

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Manager manager1 = new Manager();
    Manager manager2 = null;

    // both line 1 and line 2 are ok
    NullUtils.objectNullFieldNull(manager1, () -> manager1.getName(), "");
    NullUtils.objectNullFieldNull(manager1, manager1::getName, "");

    // line 1 is ok but line 2 will throw NullPointerException
    NullUtils.objectNullFieldNull(manager2, () -> manager2.getName(), "");
    NullUtils.objectNullFieldNull(manager2, manager2::getName, "");
}
```

As we know, we can use `xxx::yyy` instead of `() -> xxx.yyy()` in Java, but if `xxx` is null, they will be different.

The version with `::` will throw a NullPointerException, but `() -> xxx.yyy()` not throw an exception until the function is actually called.

Why is this?

I use IntelliJ IDEA to code, and if the code can use `::` instead of `->`, then the IDE will show a warning, telling me to change it to use `::` (even though that would cause a NullPointerException).

How do I resolve this?

Other related code:

```
public class NullUtils {

    public static <O, R> R objectNullFieldNull(O o, Supplier<R> supplier, R orv) {
        return Objects.isNull(o) ? orv : objectNull(supplier.get(), orv);
    }

    public static <O> O objectNull(O original, O target) {
        return Objects.isNull(original) ? target : original;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Manager {

    private String code;

    private String name;

    private String mobile;
}
```

Comment: I would absolutely expect `() -> xxx.yyy()` to throw a `NullPointerException` in the case where `xxx` is null.

Comment: trust me，```() -> xxx.yyy()``` will be ok even xxx is null，i have run it

Comment: I believe you've made a mistake.  The words "trust me" don't work on someone with my experience - I've been dereferencing null pointers for 30 years, and getting exceptions thrown every time.

Comment: `() -> xxx.yyy()` creates a function that will throw an NPE if the function is  executed. But it does not throw an NPE if the function is created and not executed. Whereas `xxx::yyy` throws an NPE immediately if `xxx` is null. Not sure what the actual problem is though. If you want to avoid the NPE, use the `->` version.

Comment: I'm aware that it creates a function.  But OP claims that it doesn't throw a NPE.  It will throw an NPE if you call the function that it creates.

Comment: oh will, maybe i can only use -> version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, if `xxx` is null, then `() -> xxx.yyy()` creates a function that will throw an NPE if it is called, but does not throw an exception if the function is created and not called. But `xxx::yyy` throws an NPE immediately. So if you are choosing between the two and don't want to throw an NPE, use the `->` version.

However, there's another option. Your `objectNullFieldNull` method is somewhat confusingly written, because the object passed as the first argument has no clear relationship with the supplier passed as the second argument. It would seem more natural (to me) for the second argument to be a function using the first, like this:

```
public static <O, R> R objectNullFieldNull(O o, Function<? super O, R> field, R orv) {
    return o==null ? orv : objectNull(field.apply(o), orv);
}
```

You can make use of it like this:

```
objectNullFieldNull(manager2, Manager::getName, "")
```

or like this

```
objectNullFieldNull(manager2, m -> m.getName(), "")
```

and neither will NPE if `manager2` is null.

`Manager::getName` is a `Function<Manager, String>` that accepts a manager (or null) as its argument, and attempts to call `getName()` on it. See [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html): *Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type*.

Comment: thx～ u have solve my problem

Comment: i add another static function u suggest to me~ 

i have another question：
```Manager::getName``` can use as ```Function<? super O, R> field``` why ? does it because Class's method truth first argument is ```this``` ?

i never use Class::ClassMethod，how the argument matched?

Comment: could u please give some reference link or statistic that i can study by myself，or give me some key word that i can search online，thx~

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html